# When EF's relationships are validated?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a problem understanding relationships in Entity Framework. The easiest will be to explain my confusion on the example. I have 3 tables, of which 2 are connected 1:1 and third table totally not connected to any other table - BUT in the same database:

```
[Table("team")]
public class Team
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id", TypeName = "int")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name", TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TeamAddress TeamAddress { get; set; }
}

[Table("teamAddress")]
public class TeamAddress
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id", TypeName = "int")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("street", TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    public Team Team { get; set; }
}

[Table("foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id", TypeName = "int")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("fooName", TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string FooName { get; set; }
}
```

FluentAPI:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().HasOptional(p => p.TeamAddress).WithRequired(p => p.Team);
```

Everything works great, but when I remove (or break) fluentAPI I'm getting exception EVEN when I query `Foo` table. Does it mean that ALL tables across one DbContext are validated no matter what am I doing?

When I break `FluentAPI` and will try to do this:

```
var foo = fni.Foos.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Even though Foo is not connected to any table I'm getting this exception:

> Additional information: Unable to determine the principal end of an
>   association between the types

The question is: Why am I getting exception about relationship between Team and TeamAddress tables, while querying not related Foo table?